# Unable to draw a rectangle in the correct position with mousemove event handler in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am attempting to make a pong clone using `canvas`. I however seem to have a misunderstanding how the coordinate system works in canvas in regards to events.

I have created a `playerPaddle` class. With this class I want the center of the paddle to be drawn exactly where the mouse is hovering:

```
// Paddle Object
function Paddle( h, w, x, y, fill) {
    this.h = h;
    this.w = w;
    this.midH = h / 2;

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.fill = fill;
}

Paddle.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
}

Paddle.prototype.updatePos = function(y) {
    this.y = y - this.midH
}
```

I thought the correct way to offset the paddle so that the center of the paddle is on the `mousemove` event would be to draw the rectangle by subtracting half the paddle height from the new position of the paddle like I am doing in the `updatePos` method above.

However this seems to not be working correctly as it is drawing the top of my paddle exactly where the `mousemove` event is occurring.

What does work though is if I subtract `this.h` from the y location of the event, which makes absolutely no sense to me.

Below is the code I use to instantiate the paddle, add the event handler to the `canvas` element itself, and the function I use to render everything.

```
// Paddle Globals
var paddleHeight = 50,
    paddleWidth = 10,
    paddleOffset = 10;
var playerPaddle = new Paddle( paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleOffset, midY, '#FFFFFF');

// Does the actual rendering
function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);
    playerPaddle.draw(ctx);
}

//Event Handlers
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var position = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var y = e.clientY - position.top;
    playerPaddle.updatePos(y);
}, false);
```

Also here is an example of the behavior that I am describing: http://jsfiddle.net/u57QD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solve the problem.
Try to delete the css style on Canvas.
I think the padding-top is making you canvas downward. So it look like the y - this.midH is not working :D Good luck

Delete follow line of code in stylesheet

```
padding-top: 20px;
```

Comment: Arggh... so my understanding of the canvas coordinate system was correct, just that I had some silly CSS in the way. Thanks for spotting this.

Comment: @Nic Young Btw, I usually use canvas.offsetTop to get the upper margin :D